# error: type mismatch: expected `usize`, found `i64` with a `Vec<i64>`

Tags: rust, type-mismatch

```
fn main() {
    let mut a: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();

    let n = 42;
    a.push(n);

    let i = 0;
    a[i];

    let j = n;

    i == j;
}
```

I am not able to fix type mismatch in rust, error says:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:10
  |
4 |     i == j;
  |          ^ expected usize, found i64
```

Comment: Your `a` could be written as `(1..1000001).collect()`

Comment: @Boiethios this just a sample code , my actual purpose is to import a list of integers from a file into vector {a} real problem lies in if condition to stop printing loop

Comment: You can use `collect` in this case as well…

Comment: @Stargateur About your edit: the minimal program to demonstrate the problem the OP is asking about is not necessarily the minimal program to demonstrate the error the OP is receiving. I do not know whether the OP is asking why `i` and `j`'s types are what they are, or why `usize` and `i64` cannot be compared. (And you shouldn't be editing at all to enforce your personal brace style, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263115.)

Comment: @hvd Rust has a standard format style, and this is good to use it. Furthermore, the OP did not format the code at all.

Comment: @hvd I tried to transform this question to something useful for futur reader, this is better ?

Comment: @Stargateur I think so, much appreciated. (Of course, the OP is free to disagree and edit or roll back, but in that case hopefully the OP would explain why they still disagree. :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is saying that you cannot compare `i` (type `usize`) and `j` (type `i64`).

Why is `i` type `usize`? Because you're using it as an index in `a[i]`.

Why is `j` type `i64`? Because you've initialised it from `n`, which has type `i64` because it is pushed into a `Vec<i64>`.

Why can you not compare the two? Because in languages where you can, that would be done by either converting `usize` to `i64` and then performing the comparison, or by converting `i64` to `usize` and then performing the comparison. Both approaches can potentially do the wrong thing.